# word alignment in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I have a sentence as string.

```
internal var sentence:string = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.";
```

Then I was separated every word and stored in an array named wordArray and apply to text field and added to stage using addChild.

```
for(var i:uint =0;x i< sentence.split(" ").length; i++){
     wordArray.push(sentence.split(" ")[i]);
     txt = new TextField();
     addChild(txt);
     txt.text = wordArray[i];
}
```

Alignement

```
if(i==0) { txt.x = wordArray[i].x;}
else{ txt.x = wordArray[i -1].width + wordArray[i-1].x+2};
```

This will align first line perfectly. I want to do with multiline with particular width like TextField.(If word exceeds the boundary limit it has to come to the next line like textField)

?

Comment: Could you explain more your problem ?

Comment: wait what, you separated the string into an array, thus its an array filled with strings. but strings don't have properties like width or x?

Comment: 1 - To store something in a standard array we use : `array[i] = value;` or `array.push(value);` so I don't know why you used : `array[i].push(value); ` ? 2 - What's `array[i].x` and `array[i].width`, we are always speaking about strings stored into an array ? 3 - Try to help us by explaining your problem to give us the possibility to help you to resolve it, and as you know, we are not paid to do anything here !

Comment: Did you know that `for` loop to put the words into `wordArray` is totally redundant? `wordArray = sentence.split(" ");` is all you need there. Now please explain your question.

Comment: Edited my question. I think its enough to get my point.

Comment: Grrrr, calling `Array.split()` to first grab length, then split the array?! Hindu code? Also, how about calling `join('\n')` after splitting and stuffing the result in a `TextArea` with wrapping off and aligning to center?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I'll fix you mistakes.

```
internal var sentence:string

var sentence:String
```

The default access modifier is internal. You don't need to write internal here.
There is no `string` class/object in AS3. For strings use `String`.

---

```
for (var i:uint = 0;x i< sentence.split(" ").length; i++){
```

What is `x` before `i <`? Remove it.

---

In your code the sentence splits multiple times. To avoid this split your sentence once.

```
var splittedSentence:Array = sentence.split(" ");

for (var i: uint = 0; i < splittedSentence.length; i++)
```

---

Next.

```
wordArray.push(sentence.split(" ")[i]);
txt = new TextField();
addChild(txt);
txt.text = wordArray[i];
```

You don't need to store a substring in the `wordArray`. But you should store all TextFields.

```
txt = new TextField();
addChild(txt);
txt.text = sentence.split(" ")[i];
wordArray.push(txt);
```

---

Define variable `line` which stores current line of the text (from 0).

```
var line:int = 0;
```

---

Set `autoSize` property to the TextField:

```
txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
```

So the width and the height of the TextField will be resized after the text will be added to the TextField.

---

```
if (txt.x + txt.width > stage.stageWidth)
{
    txt.x = 0;
    line++;
}
```

[image]

If the current TextField is out of bounds, it will be moved to the next line.

Finally, set up `y` property of the TextField:

```
txt.y = txt.height * line;
```

Full code:

```
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

var sentence: String = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.";
var wordArray: Array = [];
var txt: TextField;

var line:int = 0;

var splittedSentence:Array = sentence.split(" ");

for (var i: uint = 0; i < splittedSentence.length; i++)
{
    txt = new TextField();
    txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    addChild(txt);
    txt.text = splittedSentence[i];

    wordArray.push(txt);

    if (i == 0)
        txt.x = wordArray[i].x;
    else
        txt.x = wordArray[i - 1].width + wordArray[i - 1].x + 2;

    if (txt.x + txt.width > stage.stageWidth)
    {
        txt.x = 0;
        line++;
    }

    txt.y = txt.height * line;
}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd say use a multilined `TextField` with a center-aligned format.

```
var sentence:String="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.";
var altered:String=sentence.split(" ").join("\n");
var ta:TextField=new TextField();
ta.multiline=true; // makes a text area out of a text field, necessary
var tf:TextFormat=new TextFormat("Arial",12); // whatever
tf.align=TextFormatAlign.CENTER; // necessary
ta.defaultTextFormat=tf;
ta.text=altered;
addChild(ta);
// now we can get proper text height and actually do whatever we wish.
```

And if you are missing word wrap functionality, you should not use `altered` but use original `sentence`, and set `ta.wordWrap=true;`.